# The method seaborn.set_theme() does not work

Tags: python, seaborn

In a jupyter notebook, I run

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stat
```

and then in another cell, I run `sns.set_theme()`, and I get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'set_theme'.
```

But it should according to https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html

Why is that?

Comment: `This function was added in v0.11, and you are likely using an older version.` what is your version?

Comment: My version is 0.10

Comment: Try updating your version then :)

Comment: or use 'seaborn.set' which is an alias in the current version

Comment: @Ahmadhassan Many thanks ;)

By the way, when I run conda install -c anaconda seaborn, my anaconda says that it's already installed, but when I check, I still have version 0.10, instead of 0.11.

Comment: @Ahmadhassan if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. ;)

Comment: Just uninstall it, then install again by specifying the version  `conda install seaborn=0.11.0`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sns.set_theme()` function was added in v0.11, and you are likely using an older version.
To install the v0.11.0 or v0.11.1
`conda install seaborn=0.11`

The functionality previously existed under the name `sns.set`, and it continues to on newer versions, so updating is not strictly necessary. If you would like the functionality on an older version of seaborn, you can run `seaborn.set()`, which is an alias for `sns.set_theme()` in 0.11+.

Answer (score 6):

`seaborn.set_theme` was added in version 0.11.0; if you are on an earlier version, it will not be available. But it is a new name for the previously existing `seaborn.set` function, which remains available as an alias.

Updating your seaborn will solve the problem, but there were some [important API changes](http://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html) in seaborn 0.11.0 to be aware of. Therefore, I would not recommend blindly updating just to make the `set_theme` name available. (I do recommend updating to version 0.11, but you should take time to understand how the API changes impact your code first).

Comment: thanks. I accepted Ahmad answer, because in an earlier comment he had already pointed to the same fact.;)

Comment: Fair enough, and I don't care about the internet points, but I took the liberty of editing the accepted answer to clarify that updating is not strictly necessary. Many people will blindly run the code in an accepted StackOverflow answer, and this is a situation where they may not want to do that...